# Why elasticsearch request body query analyzer not working?

Tags: elasticsearch

When I use the simplest get query ( /index/_search?q=北京 ) , the results seems normal. But when I use the request body query , like below:

```
{
    'query': {
        'query_string':{
            'query': '北京'
        }
    }
}
```

It seems elasticsearch not use analyzer I specific by the mapping setting, even I add the analyzer setting in the query body.

Can anyone help me find out what's wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Which analyzer have you specified in your mapping, resp. your query?

Comment: I use ik analyzer (https://github.com/medcl/elasticsearch-analysis-ik). query is '电路原理' , should be '电路 原理', but seems it has a separated '理'.

Comment: What is your index complete mapping?